# Isn't "atomic energy" a misleading/wrong term? Isn't "Nuclear energy" more accurate?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

When I hear about atomic energy, they are usually talking about [nuclear fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission) or [fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion), because both of those involve the nucleus of the atom.

In contrast, "atomic energy" easily includes chemical energy such as that released by burning of carbon (carbon and oxygen atoms). Whereas actual nuclear energy has got nothing to do with the rest of the atom, and hence is NOT actually atomic energy at all.

Is there a reason why we stuck to such a seemingly obviously wrong term?

Comment: Do you mean 'molecular' energy?

Comment: An *atomic bomb* was used around 70 years ago. I don't think people nowadays call a *nuclear weapon* an *atomic* weapon.

Comment: @Rathony: Oh, they do. _Atomic_ and _nuclear_ are used almost interchangeably; for one thing, _atomic_ is much easier to say than _nuclear_ --  even native speakers metathesize it into _nucular_  pretty frequently. The OP simply needs to learn the distinction between a name (which is arbitrary) and a description (which is not arbitrary, and therefore **can** be misleading or wrong). _Atomic energy_ is a name, a fixed phrase, and not a description; certainly not a detailed description. But it doesn't need to be.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't think this question belongs here. Google has the number of hits more than 10 times for "*nuclear* weapon' than "atomic weapon".  I am the one who doesn't trust it, though.

Comment: That's printed matter. Real language is different from what gets written down.

Comment: I don't think many people ever used the term 'atomic bomb'. [**Atom bomb**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13-exDYdf3I), on the other hand...

Comment: @JHCL It was used [a lot](http://global.britannica.com/event/Manhattan-Project)

Comment: @people There's no need to fall out.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Amen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a cross-language question, and its answer depends on the context. *Nuclear* is certainly more accurate in a scientific context, but in a text for the general public *atomic* (energy, bomb, etc.) might have the same meaning but carry some extra emotional impact. It is the same in other european languages (it: atomico/nucleare, de: Atom/Kern, etc.).

Comment: Emotional impact due to past usage of "atomic" being attached to atom bombs?